# program is not returning the expected values

Tags: c#, function, class, methods, return

This is for an assignment, please see question and the code i wrote below.

The question:
In the U.S coin system, the penny is the basic coin, and it is equal to cent, a nickel is equivalent to 5 cents, a dime is equivalent to 10 cents, a quarter is equivalent to 25 cents, and half-dollar is equivalent to 50 cents. Design and implement a program that would make use of the functions shown below. Each function has a single int formal parameter Amount.
a) HalfDollars (): Compute the maximum number of half-dollars that could be used in making change for Amount.
b) Quarters():Compute the maximum number of quarter that could be used in making change for Amount
c) Dimes ():Compute the maximum number of dimes that could be used in making change for Amount
d) Nickels () : Compute the maximum number of nickels that could be used in making change for Amount

The code that i wrote:

```
//Question 1
//please note, i dont have comments everywhere
```

{

```
public class MoneyCalc 
{
    public int Amount;

    //a)
    public void Half_Dollar()
    {
        int hd = 2;
        int hdOutput = Amount * hd;

        Console.WriteLine("The maximum number of half dollars for " + Amount + " is: " + hdOutput);
    }

    //b)
    public void Quater()
    {
        int q = 4;
        int qOutput = Amount * q;

        Console.WriteLine("The maximum number of half dollars for " + Amount + " is: " + qOutput);
    }

    //c)
    public void Dimes()
    {
        int d = 10;
        int dOutput = Amount * d;

        Console.WriteLine("The maximum number of half dollars for " + Amount + " is: " + dOutput);
    }

    //d)
    public void Nickles()
    {
        int n = 20;
        int nOutput = Amount * n;

        Console.WriteLine("The maximum number of half dollars for " + Amount + " is: " + nOutput);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //the main program.
        //everything is initialised here.

        //gets the amount the ser wants to calculate through user input in a string and converts to to an integer.
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter an amount to calculate:");
        string userAmount = Console.ReadLine();
        int amount = Int32.Parse(userAmount);

        //users have to make a selection from this list.
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose what you want to calculate you amount to (Select the number):");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Half Dollar");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Quater");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Dime");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Nickel");

        //gets the users input(their choice) in a string and coverts it to an integer
        string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        int choice = Int32.Parse(userAmount);

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            MoneyCalc moneycalc = new MoneyCalc();
            moneycalc.Amount = amount;

            moneycalc.Half_Dollar();
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            MoneyCalc moneycalc = new MoneyCalc();
            moneycalc.Amount = amount;

            moneycalc.Quater();
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            MoneyCalc moneycalc = new MoneyCalc();
            moneycalc.Amount = amount;

            moneycalc.Dimes();
        }
        else if (choice == 4)
        {
            MoneyCalc moneycalc = new MoneyCalc();
            moneycalc.Amount = amount;

            moneycalc.Nickles();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option");
        }


    }
}
}
```

Comment: What input did you give it? What output did it give? What did you expect?

Comment: Please read [ask]. You don't only need to learn to program, you also need to learn to debug. Start by writing down some input and what output you expect. Then run your program and when the actual output doesn't match your expectations, set breakpoints and step through your code to inspect your variables. And if you want help, you need to explain to us as well what behavior you expect and what you observe, and what you have tried to fix the code. Edit: or what @Sweeper says, in short.

Comment: @PaulF that part looks ok - there are two half dollars in Amount is 1 dollar, ten dimes etc.

Comment: The assignment specifies that you need to use a parameter for your functions. Also look into return values instead of printing from it

Comment: Sorry for being vague. So when i run the code, in the console, it asks me to enter the value i want to calculate, and then to select the option (As i expected). Once i select the option, the console window just closes. i will try and look into return values.

Comment: hahahaha. sure *"the console window just closes"* - you need to add `Console.ReadKey()` and after that `goto line1` where `line1` is  marker before `Console.WriteLine("Please enter an amount to calculate:");`

Comment: @T.S. Please don't use `goto` when a `while(true){...}` or something like that would be clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, what they looking for is

```
// amount expected in $$, $2.34
public int GetNumberOfCoins(decimal amount, CoinOption centValue)
{
    // you might want to check first if result of truncate is larger than max int value
    int numberOfCoins = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(amount * 100 / (int)centValue));
    return numberOfCoins;
}

// And then in your console
public enum CoinOption : int
{
    Penny = 1,
    Nickel = 5,
    Dime = 10,
    Quarter = 25,
    Half = 50
}

string answer = null;
CoinOption opt;
switch (inputOption)
{
    case "1":
        opt = CoinOption.Penny;
        break;
    case "2":
        opt = CoinOption.Nickel;
        break;
    case "3":
        opt = CoinOption.Dime;
        break;
    case "4":
        opt = CoinOption.Quarter;
        break;
    case "5":
        opt = CoinOption.Half;
        break;
}

// inputAmount originally comes as string but needs to be converted to decimal
answer = GetNumberOfCoins(inputAmount, opt).ToString()
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me sort my code out. it is now working to how I'd like it to. And yes, i figured out that i needed to use 'Console.ReadKey()' to keep the console from closing. This is the first piece of code that I've written with C#, so i am still learning.

Comment: @Trishen Good. This is pretty complex for the "first code". First code is usually `Console.WriteLine("Hello World")`. Yes, your main issue was math formulas and `ReadKey`. Reading your question, I see that I might gone too far in making it good and created one method vs many. But who said, `copy\paste` is not a pattern?